# Virtualbox delete vm ram

Tags: virtualbox, ram

If I delete a VM in VirtualBox, what happens with the RAM I used to create that VM? Is it freed?

Answer (score 1):

The RAM is freed as soon as you turn off the VM. So yes, if you delete it, the RAM is freed.